# How to edit the Ajax HTML Editor, that I only need a few buttons of it?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, html-editor

I use the HTML Editor from ASP.NET Ajax AjaxControlToolkit http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx.

Its like: http://s3.imgimg.de/uploads/2889172fdJPG.jpg

But I want to have it like: http://s3.imgimg.de/uploads/3eda09893JPG.jpg

So the default buttons are much overpowered for my users.
Is there a way to reduce the ajax HTMLEditor to this few buttons?
Or is there another controle you can help me with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which one you're using. I would recommend using TinyMCE: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

It will be easy to achieve what you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to take advice from Ed Pitt, I did it this way and I was able to create different versions with different tools. The basic premise is to copy the HTMLEditor.Samples.cs file from the AJAX Control Toolkit source into your app and modify it to only print out the toolbars you want:

http://dot-net-web-developer-bristol.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-ajax-htmleditor-top-toolbar.html

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hey cool, that's my blog you just linked to, so feel free to upvote this comment for some credit :)